# ¿Cómo hacer un IF en un JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero seleccionar rows de una tabla que uso en un join solo si la propriedad `is_evil = 0`.

*Wands* Table: [image]
*Wands_Property* Table: [image]

Entonces intenté:

```
SELECT IF(Wands_Property.is_evil = 0, (id, age, coins_needed, power),NULL) 
FROM Wands_Property 
INNER JOIN Wands 
ON Wands_Property.Code = Wands.Code
ORDER BY Power DESC
```

Sin embargo obtengo:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000) at line 8: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Comment: porque haces un if, y no un where dentro del join?ç

Comment: Cual es tu salida esperada?

Comment: El if debería retornar un resultado, intenta el if por cada campo

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar la cláusla WHERE:

Solo retornará aquellas filas del JOIN para las cuales is_evil = 0.

```
SELECT id, age, coins_needed, power
FROM Wands_Property 
INNER JOIN Wands ON Wands_Property.Code = Wands.Code
WHERE Wands_Property.is_evil = 0
ORDER BY Power DESC;
```